# RegEx for Flexible Time Validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've begun with a regular expression for time validation,
it should detect strings like:

```
5s
3h5m
5h3m02s
05:03:02
05:03
4
```

My current regex is valid for all of these but one: **05:03**. It detects ***05*** as hours and ***03*** as seconds, but it should be 05 as minutes... and I don't know how to edit my code to do this.

```
 var reTime =
 /^(?:PT)?(?:(\d{1,2})[:.hH])?(?:(\d{1,4})[:.mM])?(?:(\d{1,6})[sS]?)?$/;
```

Comment: Do you really, *really* need to do this with a single regular expression? Using one for the "tagged" version (`3h5m`, etc.) and one for the positional version (`05:03`, etc.) would be *far* simpler to read and maintain.

Comment: This problem (validating time input) has so many facets, that can go horribly wrong. E.g., have you heard of [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)? Yes, that's right, you can have 61 seconds under certain circumstances. It is of extreme importance, that you define _clearly_, under what conditions the regex shall be used and what the expected outcome is.

Comment: @Boldewyn I've never heard of leap seconds and am curious under which circumstance I would be able to come across such a state. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: On second thought, Google is my friend. Lol

Comment: I also linked to the Wikipedia article above. Tl;dr: It's a way to cater for minimal time differences caused by Earth's a bit irregular orbit around the sun.

Answer (score -1):

Test this one :

```
var hasTimeFormat = function (input) {
        var timeFormat = /([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})\,([0-9]{3})$/;
        if (typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
            String.prototype.trim = function () {
                return input.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
            }
        }
        return timeFormat.test(input.trim());
    }
```

This works well (for example for "05:03:02,677") and if you wanna add something more, you can add easily.

Comment: At first glance I don't see how that handles all test cases. I'm not very good at RegEx I'll admit but I just don't see it

Comment: @user3054287 That's… just wrong. What is that comma doing there? How is this supposed to match `5h3m02s`? Why are you escaping colon and comma?!